# bounded DataGridView modify last row (new row) programatically

Tags: c#, datagridview

When I modify the last row (new row,NewRowIndex) in the DataGridView eprogramatically either it does not create a new row, as it does when you enter data using keyboard or if I add a new row to the DataTable it will add two rows instead of one. Any ideas how to handle this ?

```
     int rowIndex = dataEntryGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
     GridModel gm = (GridModel)dataEntryGridView.DataSource;
     if (gm == null) return;
     int rowCount = gm.Rows.Count; // to many additions
     //int rowCount = dataEntryGridView.Rows.Count; // no adition
     if (dataEntryGridView.AllowUserToAddRows)
     {
        nrRows = rowsInClipboard.Length;
        if (rowCount < (rowIndex + nrRows) && gm != null )
              gm.AddRows(rowIndex + nrRows - rowCount);
     }
     int colIndex = dataEntryGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;
     int colCount = dataEntryGridView.Columns.Count;
     for (int iRow = 0; iRow < nrRows; iRow++)
     {
        string[] valuesInRow = rowsInClipboard[iRow].Split(columnSplitter);
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < valuesInRow.Length; iCol++)
        {
           if (colCount > colIndex + iCol)
           {
              DataGridViewCell cell = dataEntryGridView.Rows[rowIndex + iRow].Cells[colIndex + iCol];
              if (!cell.ReadOnly)
              {
                 gm.Rows[rowIndex + iRow][colIndex + iCol] = valuesInRow[iCol];
                 //cell.Value = valuesInRow[iCol];
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: B Csaba I would suggest breaking that code out into 2 separate methods also use better naming convention for your variables.. really makes it hard to read.. also if you said it works for when `as it does when you enter data using keyboard` why not look at that method in the KeyPress Events and duplicate similar logic ..

Comment: Seems DataGridView does not bound to DataSource properly.
DataSource has the correct number of rows.

Comment: DataSource is a DataTable

Comment: Ultimately I added a code to delete the wrongly added row